# Database structure for app to show random items once to users

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, structure

I am trying to design an app (mobile + web) that displays random items stored in a database to the Users.

The issue I have is that I do not know how I should design such a database. The idea is that all users are logged in to use the app and that they get random items on the screens and can then swipe to the next one. The app should keep track of all the items that the user has already seen and never ever show them again. You could think of it as a similar app then Tinder but its not for dating.

I know how I should structure my database to store the items but I do not know what the best practice for such a use case would be. Should i create the complete items database for every new User and then delete the items from it that they have already seen? Or is there another (better) way to do this ? I can't really think of another way for now and my Project is stuck on this crucial part.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: You should just keep a list (for each user) of item IDs that the user has seen. This has two advantages. 1) when the list of items grows, the per user information doesn't need to be updated. 2) When the list of items grows much larger, the number of items a typical user has seen will be much smaller than the full list of items.

Comment: Ok but wouldnt it be too inefficient to always choose a random item that the User has not seen yet ? I would need to check against all the items the user has in his list and choose one that is not part of it ?

Comment: If the number of items that the user has seen is much smaller than the total number of items (e.g. 10% or less), then there's a low probability of selecting an item that's already been seen. If the randomly selected item *is* a duplicate, then just try again.